# NTFS partition crashes chkdsk

Tags: windows, ntfs, chkdsk

Unfortunately I had a couple of hard resets on a machine and it seems to have damaged an NTFS partition.  O/S is Windows 2012R2.

```
C:\Users\Administrator>chkdsk d:
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Volume label is XXXXXXX.

WARNING!  F parameter not specified.
Running CHKDSK in read-only mode.

Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...
  18085632 file records processed.
File verification completed.
  5195 large file records processed.
  0 bad file records processed.

Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...
  18240430 index entries processed.
Index verification completed.
CHKDSK is scanning unindexed files for reconnect to their original directory.
  1 unindexed files scanned.
An unspecified error occurred (6672732e637878 56f).
```

Any suggestions other than reformat/restore from backup to fix the partition?

Comment: if you run two time with /f, does it finish by passing ?

Comment: (and be sure to run the cmd as an admin too please, I specify it as usually as an admin it will run into the path c:\windows\system32)

Comment: nope, no combination of flags and repeating helped.  what DID wind up eventually fixing it was nuking a corrupted directory and rerunning.  seems to be a bug in chkdsk.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check S.M.A.R.T first.

In the Command Prompt window, type the following commands, pressing Enter after each:

**wmic**

**diskdrive get status**

Or you can use CrystalDiskInfo 
http://crystalmark.info/download/index-e.html

If HDD health is NOT OK, you need to change it. If HDD health is OK, you can try to repair by using

**chkdsk /f D:**   and   **chkdsk /r D:**

Comment: thanks for the tip.  did that.  physical drives are fine.